# Tensorboard compute time

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I try to figure out where in computation graph I lose time. I assumed that ApplyFtrl cost a lot, but from [my tensorboard](http://104.198.254.196:6006/) it looks like such operations as **Identity**, **LoopCond** and **Exit** take a lot of time. Am I right? And how I can improve training time for my graph?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of your TensorBoard output (e.g. as an image in the question)? The link to your TensorBoard doesn't work, presumably because it is behind a firewall or NAT.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to allow 6006 port. Now it should work.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/N1XxomeUuZjUK link to the log file.